# WindowManager animation with "WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY" property in accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am developing an application which has Accessibility service. With this service I will do my back end functionality(button clicks and navigating to other screens) by showing a window manager screen on top. In this window manager screen I need to add any animation(in worst case, I have to add a simple progress bar). My issue is,

**1)** If I add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` (For Lollipop and below) **OR** `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY` (For Marshmallow and above) property to window manager, I am successfully completing back end functionality but animation is hanging. It is occurring for simple progress bar also.

**2)** If I add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE` to window manager, I am successfully showing animation but back end functionality is not working.

Any minor help is appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am not answering , but suggesting you. just take help of any screen lock project from GitHub open source and with same idea you can achieve your goal.   instead using activity use service, singleton, and inflate view with window manager

Comment: "accessibility service", these projects won't help him. Accessibility services have special restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty in accessibility services with adding views is getting the correct permissions. Your approach on approach one is correct. The performance issues in such animations area an unrelated issue. Once a view has been successfully added to the window manager any concerns with view performance are similar to concerns as if you were in the context of an activity. Unless, you have some type of memory leak, view leak, etc. Adding overlay views to the window manager directly is prone to mismanagement, because you also have to remove those views yourself. Otherwise old instances of overlays will stick around forever and bog down performance.

Stick with option one from your services point of view and figure out your performance issues outside of the scope of this decision. They are only indirectly related. Your performance problem is not directly caused by this decision, but rather mistakes elsewhere. What these could be I can only provide a speculative answer on.